# How to create a function to accept concatenated source value - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create a vba function to replace multiple characters from cell value. I'm calling this function 'TestFunction' for now. The purpose of the function is to parse illegal characters from the data to be able to use it and the original data needs to remain in their own columns after parse.

I have pasted my code and table as a reference.

[image: + screen capture from original test]

To use the function I would like to use `=TestFunction(...)` on a helper column on the same row as the data is in. The code works for a single reference e.g. `=TestFunction(A1)`, but when trying to pass concatenated reference e.g. `=TestFunction(A1&A2)` it returns `#VALUE!`.

I've tried to fix this for a while with no success. I could make another helper column where the concatenated data is but I would really love to get this function to work without additional column.

Anyone know if this is possible to achieve?

Reference code:

```
Function TestFunction(CellContents As Range) As String
  Dim CellTextReplaced As String
  Dim char As Variant
  ' Characters to be replaced with "|" as delimiter
  Const SpecialCharacters As String = ".|,|!| |/|\|+|-|@|&"

  ' Replace all special characters
  CellTextReplaced = CellContents.Value
    For Each char In Split(SpecialCharacters, "|")
      CellTextReplaced = Replace(CellTextReplaced, char, "")
    Next
  ' Output

  TestFunction = CellTextReplaced
End Function
```

Reference table:

```
  |   A    |    B     |        C           |          D           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | .test  |   .test  |  =TestFunction(A1) | =TestFunction(A1&B1) |
2 | ,test  |   ,test  |  =TestFunction(A2) | =TestFunction(A2&B2) |
3 | test-  |   test-  |  =TestFunction(A3) | =TestFunction(A3&B3) |
4 | /test\ |   /test\ |  =TestFunction(A4) | =TestFunction(A4&B4) |
```

Comment: The concatenated one is a string, not a range.

Comment: Change the `UDF()` to accept a `String` rather than a `Range.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your function `TestFunction(CellContents As Range)` was waiting for a `Range` but `A1&B1` actually is a `String` because the concatenation with `&` casts the values of the two ranges `A1` and `B1` into a string.

I suggest the following improvements:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function TestFunction(ByVal CellContents As String) As String
    Const SpecialCharacters As String = ".,! /\+-@&"

    Dim iChar As Long
    For iChar = 1 To Len(SpecialCharacters)
        CellContents = Replace$(CellContents, Mid$(SpecialCharacters, iChar, 1), "")
    Next iChar

    TestFunction = CellContents
End Function
```